# DD IE6 PNG problem with Ajax Modal Window

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png

Currently i'm using DDIEPNG (http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) as my IE6 png headache pill, but i hit a problem with ajax modal window....

I'm trying to create modal window using lightbox gone wild tiny js script with a little tweak that suit my problem... and it create modal window "content" on the fly base on the url given to lightbox... but it's seem DDIEPNG can't parse the new content base on ajax call....

R there any solution regarding these problem ?, or do i need to use another PNG fix js ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

A HTC-based PNG fix would be much easier in your case.
For example http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/